# Subscription rest-hook in FHIR HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, hook, webhooks, subscription, hl7-fhir

I created a simple Rest Endpoint in java using jersey as you see in the following:

```
  @Path("/study")
  public class CreateRestEndpoint {
  private static String endpoint;

  @PUT
  @Consumes("application/fhir+json") 
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
  public Response  getPut(IBaseResource list){
    System.out.println("UpdatedResource.: "+list);   
    return Response.status(200).build();
}


  @PUT
  public Response getTest(String str) {
    System.out.printf(str);
    return Response.status(200).build();
  }
```

When I use postman and I send a PUT request to jersey-servlet, everything is ok and the jersey-servlet gets the message immediately.
But I created jersey-servlet to get a message which is sent by FHIR server  (my FHIR server is running in docker) via Subscription resource. Actually, I'm trying to use subscription mechanism to be notified when a List resource is updated.:

```
 {
  "resourceType": "Subscription",
  "id": "9",
  "meta": {
    "versionId": "2",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-11-08T09:05:33.366+00:00",
    "tag": [
      {
        "system": "http://hapifhir.io/fhir/StructureDefinition/subscription-matching-strategy",
        "code": "IN_MEMORY",
        "display": "In-memory"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "active",
  "reason": "Monitor Screening List",
  "criteria": "List?code=http://miracum.org/fhir/CodeSystem/screening-list|screening-recommendations",
  "channel": {
    "type": "rest-hook",
    "endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/notification/study",
    "payload": "application/fhir+json"
  }
}
```

When I change the List resources in FHIR, I expected to arrive a message in the jersey-servlet but unfortunately I get the following error (when I set the endpoint to a test rest-hook like webhook.site samples, I can get the message from FHIR side):

> fhir_1     | 2019-11-08 18:48:40.688 [subscription-delivery-rest-hook-9-13] INFO  c.u.f.j.s.m.i.S.SUBS6 [SubscriptionDebugLogInterceptor.java:162] Delivery of resource List/4/_history/17 for subscription Subscription/9 to channel of type RESTHOOK - Failure: ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
>   fhir_1     | Exception in thread "subscription-delivery-rest-hook-9-13" org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure handling subscription payload for subscription: Subscription/9; nested exception is **ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found,** failedMessage=ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.subscription.module.subscriber.ResourceDeliveryJsonMessage@330c0fdb[myPayload=ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.subscription.module.subscriber.ResourceDeliveryMessage@38a1c8a2[mySubscription=ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.subscription.module.CanonicalSubscription@1d55d025[myIdElement=Subscription/9,myStatus=ACTIVE,myCriteriaString=List?..........
>   ..................................................

What is the problem? I tried a lot with different parameters but no solution found.

Comment: It would help if you actually identified the server software you are testing witn

Comment: @GrahameGrieve We created an FHIR server and it's running in docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed @Path to  @Path("/study/List/{var}"), but I got the same failure again. Actually my FHIR server is running in docker and probability the problem would be inside the Docker. 
After setting the Proxy in Docker, everything fine...
Conclusion: I had to change the @path to @Path("/study/List/{var}")and set the Proxy in Docker.